# How to add value of $user variable to button name?

Tags: php, html, variables, button

im trying to show the user's name $user on a button but i cant figure how to do it:

here's some of the code

```
    include ("config.php");
    include ("adminchk.php");   // Check if user is admin
    include ("getdir.php");
    include ("lang/lang_".$lang.".php");
if (isset($uStat) and $uStat===TRUE)
    {
        echo $GLOBALS['l_menuWelcome'] . " " . $user."\n";

        if ($admin===TRUE) echo "*";
        echo "<div class='quote'>\n";    ... etc
```

and here's the button code :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='userconnect.html'" >$user</button>
```

thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print a PHP variable in the middle of some HTML, you need to wrap it in PHP tags and use `echo`. So assuming your button code comes from a PHP file, the code looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='userconnect.html'" >
    <?php echo $user; ?>
</button>
```

#### [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)